# Copying n characters using memcpy

Tags: c++, c++11, memcpy

I am trying to copy the exact number of 32 characters with memcpy, however I'm having issues with proper usage of it as multiple online g++ compilers as well as the compiler on my machine are giving slightly different results with the same source code.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char* source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu ipsum nec elit mattis consequat. Curabitur sollicitudin ligula et quam bibendum euismod.";
    char dest[32];

    std::memcpy(&dest, source, sizeof(dest));
    std::cout << dest << "(" << strlen(dest) << ")";
}
```

Code compiled at [here](https://www.codechef.com/ide) (G++4.9.2).

Output doesn't contain 32 characters (junk values are being added):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons †¿(36)
```

Code compiled at [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1a27969454721eaa) (G++4.9).

Output contains required results:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cons(32)
```

Output on my machine is similar to the first output (36 characters).

**Why is each result different?**

**What should be the valid usage of memcpy to copy n numbers of characters?**

Comment: Your use of `memcpy` is correct but the method of determining its result is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `strlen` function and the `operator<< (const char *)` function are only suitable for C-style strings. They cannot be used to output or measure the length of arbitrary chunks of data.

Think about it -- how could they possible determine the length? What method could they possible use?

> Why is each result different?

Because you are using functions that can only be used on a C-style string on something that is not a C-style string. That's a bug that will behave differently depending on specifics about the platform's memory layout.

> What should be the valid usage of memcpy to copy n numbers of characters?

That's it. You copied the characters. But now you just have a bunch of characters, not a string. If you use functions that print bunches of characters, they'll work fine.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char* source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu ipsum nec elit mat
    char dest[32];

    std::memcpy(&dest, source, sizeof(dest));

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(dest); ++i)
        std::cout << dest[i];
}
```

Comment: So basically if I'd like to print the `dest` variable I would have to null-terminate the string or use stl methods (see @Luke answer)?

Comment: @Lucas Right. You can use code that prints a C-style string, but you have to make it a C-style string. Otherwise, use code that prints a bunch of characters.

Answer (score 3):

The `dest` is not null-terminated. Therefore functions like `strlen` or `operator <<` do not know they have reached the end of the buffer and continue further even after 32 characters have been reached. They will stop when they encounter null in the unknown memory after `dest[31]`, which can be after 10, 1000, 1000000 bytes of even not at all. What you need is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const char* source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu ipsum nec elit mattis consequat. Curabitur sollicitudin ligula et quam bibendum euismod.";
    char dest[33];

    std::memcpy(&dest, source, sizeof(dest)-1);
    dest[32] = '\0';
    std::cout << dest << "(" << strlen(dest) << ")";
}
```

Comment: Thats clever but wouldnt it be easier to use `strlcpy` which will stop copying on first null? No idea if I am right but it seems like it would be as simple as: `char dest[32 + 1]; strlcpy(&dest, source, sizeof(dest));`

Comment: Yes, that would also be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::string`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const char* source = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu ipsum nec elit mattis consequat. Curabitur sollicitudin ligula et quam bibendum euismod.";

    std::string s(source, 32);
    std::cout << s << "(" << s.length() << ")";
}
```

For memcpy, you usually don't want to use it on c-style strings, because the length of the string is the size of the memory block minus 1.

Comment: I like that solution. Could it be used to send buffered packets as well? I mean: `const char* n = "Something"; network->Packet(std::string(n, 32).c_str() /* const void* data */, 32 /* size */);`

Answer (score 1):

This is because the strange method in memory allocation in C++.

One of the solutions is by determining the length of the array.
If an array is defined inside a function, it will not be shown as if it was full of **nul**s. More obviously, the strlen() function calculates the length of the string by finding the first **nul** byte. Inside a function, a variable is not initially intialized, and will contain arbitrary data. This piece of memory, is directly taken from the operating system heap.

If you put the array outside like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char dest[32];

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
....
```

It will function properly because any variable declared outside functions are initially initialized zero.

Another way to solve this problem, is, like @Lucas said, leaving one byte empty outside, i.e.:

```
char dest[33];
memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(char) * 32);
```

This is not affected by whether the array is located outside the function or not.

In details, the strlen function is similar to this in principle:

```
int strlen(char* str)
{
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
        if (str[i] == 0)
            return i;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Some users have pointed out that I cannot gurantee the 33rd byte is empty. and now I came to a solution:

```
char dest[33];
memset(dest, 0, sizeof(char) * 33);
memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(char) * 32);
```

Or simply set the last byte as nul.

```
char dest[33];
dest[32] = 0;
```

Some safer methods and more nice-looking methods include direct memory allocation. Yet according to some statistical data, **new** commands and **malloc()** functions can cause a decrease in performance.

```
char *dest = new char[32];
memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(char) * 32);
```

**If you use the following code, you will experience unexpected results.**

```
char *dest = new char[32];
memcpy(dest, source, sizeof(char) * 32);
```

**So always remember to consider boundaries when programming in C/C++.**

Comment: You do not have any guarantee that the 33rd byte (index 32) will be empty. It will contain whatever value was there when the dest was declared.

Comment: You're confusing `NULL` (the null pointer constant) with `nul` (the zero char value used to terminate C-style strings)

Comment: I don't understand the first 2 paragraphs. "One of the solutions is by determining the length of the array" – OP already knows. "If an array is defined inside a function, it will not be shown as if it was full of nuls" – what?

Comment: @RadLexus It will not be initialized when defined inside a function. Try compiling and running by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

[memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) function does not check for any terminating null character in source - it always copies exactly num bytes. You should terminate with null.